# Need to Deploy Laravel + Reactjs (SEO friendly ) application

Tags: reactjs, laravel, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I have to create an application where users will have their unique usernames and profiles like "website.com/JohnDoe". for that the client asked me to develop it in any good PHP framework and client also need an android/ios app (which he disclosed after 2nd meeting) . so I was(before 2nd meeting) going to use Laravel totally. but since he said he wanted a mobile app too, so I decided to use Laravel as backend API, for Web frontend I will use Reactjs and for Mobile I would use ReactNative ( I've done same before). since Laravel provides react support so my I was planning to use React within the laravel.

Then client said he is more concern about SEO of his website. so I had two options

1. Use laravel as API provider only. and create ReactJS app totally separate from Laravel.
   In this case I will need Nodejs server. Then I thought If I have a nodejs server than why would I go for laravel, I could use Express.
2. Use ReactJS within laravel and use any SSR package to cope with ssr.

If I am going for second option, can anyone point me to already live website which uses React Helmet SSR or Laravel-react-ssr?

Laravel react-ssr: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering
React Helmet-ssr: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage

I have read both, and I am too confused. I am beginner in both Laravel and React(node) so I am unable to understand what both are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

i deployed your 2 option mentioned let me give you the site https://v3.topviewnyc.com/, i created a microservice which would take care of SSR besides my hooks and components are build on react so am totally able of enjoy the SPA frontend side with react using components and get data via laravels API